# Not able to fetch image path from MySQL to PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display image path from MySQL but it is erroring out as undefined array key when I try displaying the images.

**AUTH.PHP**
As you can see I have defined the image database column here in this file.

```
$user_image = $user['image'];
$_SESSION['user_image'] = $user_image;
```

**NAV.PHP**
And as you can see here I have defined the current user in session's image name.

```
<img src="../assets/images/<?=$_SESSION['user_image']?>">
```

[image]

So, AUTH.PHP is where all the selecting of table is happening and in NAV.PHP I am trying to display the image in the IMG tag. The image column is saved as a text on the MySQL table. NAV.PHP is display an invalid array key error. Please help me out. Another thing I would like to point out is that I am making the connection to MySQL through PDO not mysqli.

Comment: have you started the session? Its started in auth.php but have you done it in the other script? additionally, if nav.php is an include, you'll have issues with relative paths on all your assets when you want multi-level paths. unrelated `if ($email === $user_email) {` is superfluous, and `?error=` maybe open to XSS

Comment: The session does not need to be started in NAV.PHP as it is being included on to other pages which have there own session being started. Also, I am not really sure sorry.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/P4qOtNy.png

Comment: Please reduce the code given to the **neccessary** parts. This makes it way easier to understand your problem

Comment: As you can see I have updated the question now, it should be more understandable now and should only have the necessary parts. But I did also found a better solution so please do check my update answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very weird way of doing it but I solved it by basically first off connecting to the database through a mysqli connection as by default I was using a PDO connection the MySQL. After that I selected the image column of the current user in session and basically displayed that. Here is the code for anyone else to try:

```
            <?php
                    include '../includes/logic/db_conn_mysqli.php';

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where full_name = '".$_SESSION['user_full_name']."'";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                ?>
                <?php echo '<img src="../assets/images/' . $row['image']. '" alt="" class="header__img">'; ?>
                <?php } }?>
```

**UPDATE**
I worked on a better solution then this, now I have made it so it uses database connection file already provided instead of using a mysqli connection. It is a very simple code too now. You just need to put this code:

```
<?php  

function getUser($username, $conn){
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute([$username]);

   if ($stmt->rowCount() === 1) {
     $user = $stmt->fetch();
     return $user;
   }else {
    $user = [];
    return $user;
   }
}
```

In a file and then include it to the file where you want to display the image, also include the database connection file and then use this code:

```
$user = getUser($_SESSION['username'], $conn);
```

In this code it basically defines what the $user variable is equal to so when you use the $user or any variable you have set $user in your case to display the image it would know what users data it would need to fetch. So in my case I have made it so it fetches the current username is sessions data. Then where you need to define the source of image just put:

```
$user['image']
```

This code is basically telling the image source the specific column to use the path/filename from our database connection. Hope this helps out anyone else who had been having the same user.

Comment: Please do not use this way of selecting data. Use prepared statements to avoid SQL vulnerabilities. Also, it could help to use a **unique** identiifer to access that `users` table